# Как изменять данные структуры через адрес?

Tags: golang

Есть такая структура:

```
type DonateScene struct {
    UserID      int64
    Step        int
    Target      int
    Anonymously bool
    LastMessage string
}

var DonateScenes []DonateScene
```

Так я получаю её адрес и изменяю:

```
func DonateSceneManager(message *tgapi.Message) bool {
    userID := message.Chat.ID
    var currentScene *DonateScene

    for _, r := range DonateScenes {
        if r.UserID == userID {
            currentScene = &r
        }
    }

    if currentScene == nil {
        DonateScenes = append(DonateScenes, DonateScene{UserID: userID, Step: 1})
        return false
    }

    currentScene.Step++
    fmt.Println(currentScene.Step)
}
```

Но принтится всегда `2`. Такое чувство, что изменения сохранятся в экземпляре объекта, как будто я это делаю так:

```
var currentScene DonateScene
    
for i, r := range DonateScenes {
    if r.UserID == userID {
        currentScene = r
    }
}
currentScene.Step++ // тут понятно, что не сохранится
```

Рабочий вариант:

```
var currentScene DonateScene
var index int
for i, r := range DonateScenes {
    if r.UserID == message.Chat.ID {
        currentScene = r
        index = i
 }
}
DonateScenes[index].Step++
```

Но мне кажется, что правильно именно через первый вариант делать, так как дальше, по коду, очень много взаимодействий с этим `(DonateScenes[index])` объектом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь

```
for _, r := range DonateScenes {
    if r.UserID == userID {
        currentScene = &r
    }
}
```

вы сохраняете пойнтер на итератор `r`, а не на саму структуру в массиве.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
for idx, r := range DonateScenes {
    if r.UserID == userID {
        currentScene = &DonateScenes[idx]
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, толи я не понимаю ничего в Го(скорее всего так и есть) но вроде итератор в первом примере не `r` а `_`, а `r` в свою очередь копия объекта из среза(что странно), и возникает тогда вопрос как пробежать по срезу без копирования объектов? (и зачем во втором примере вы вообще объявили `r`? для красивой проверки условия? можно было поступить так: `for idx, _ ...... if DonateScenes[idx].UserID...`?)

Comment: Конечно r это не сам итератор, а переменная, в которую сохраняется копия объекта. Чтобы не создавать копии можно использовать только индексы или положить в слайс пойнтеры. Я старался минимально изменить код, чтобы разница между ссылкой на переменную r и ссылкой на элемент слайса была более явной.